How to prevent click outside event from closing a filter component when interacting with a calendar component in Angular?
I'm working on an Angular application where I have a filter component that toggles its visibility based on a click outside event. This works as expected, but I have an issue when there is a calendar component inside the filter area. Interacting with the calendar (e.g., selecting dates) triggers the click outside event, causing the filter component to close.
Here's my filter component code:
...

  showFilter = false;
  private globalClickListener: () => void;

  // List of classes to ignore during the click outside check
  ignoredClasses = [
    '.mat-select', 
    '.mat-datepicker', 
    'span.mat-option-text', 
    'span.mat-calendar-body-cell-content.mat-focus-indicator.mat-calendar-body-selected', 
    'button.mat-calendar-previous-button.mdc-icon-button.mat-mdc-icon-button.mat-unthemed.mat-mdc-button-base.cdk-focused.cdk-mouse-focused', 
    'button.mat-calendar-next-button.mdc-icon-button.mat-mdc-icon-button.mat-unthemed.mat-mdc-button-base.cdk-focused.cdk-mouse-focused',
    '.mat-calendar-body-cell-content.mat-calendar-body-selected' 
  ];

  constructor(
    ...
    filterService
      .openCloseFilterEvent()
      .subscribe(() => (this.showFilter = !this.showFilter));
    filterService.dataFilterEvent().subscribe(() => (this.showFilter = false));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalClickListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (event: Event) => {
      const clickedElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
      const isIgnoredElement = this.ignoredClasses.some(selector => clickedElement.closest(selector));
      if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && !isIgnoredElement) {
        this.showFilter = false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.globalClickListener) {
      this.globalClickListener();
    }
  }

  searchEmitter(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.filterService.setPage(25, 0);
    this.filterService.updateFilter(this.filter);
    this.showFilter = false;
  }
}

The ignoredClasses/isIgnoredElement was just one of my attempts, it didn't work and I am not sure why, perhaps because the calendar is not a direct parent or child? it is part of another pieces of components, they are not in the same .html file? I tried it because it works on another project I have.
Anyhow, anyone knows how I can make it work? or what else I could attempt?
I tried the ignoredClasses as an array and outside the array, I am not sure what else I can try

In general to "click outside" you don't check classes else you get the HTMLElement where is allow click.
For an Angular element you can use ViewChild, but the problem with a mat-datepicker it's that use cdk-overlay (and it's "attached" outside the app). So we can create a function to get the htmlElement
  @ViewChild('div') div:ElementRef; //<--this for our element
  subscription!:Subscription  //<--we can use fromEvent rxjs operator

  getCdkOverlayContainer(){
    const overlayContainer= document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-container')
    if (!overlayContainer )
      return null;

      const calendar=document.getElementsByTagName('mat-calendar')
      const overlay=Array.from(overlayContainer)
                           .filter((x:any)=>x.contains(calendar[0]))
    return overlay && overlay.length?overlay[0]:null
  }

  //in ngOnDestroy unsubscribe
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe;
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.subscription=fromEvent(document,'click').pipe(
      //we use filter to not execute nothing
      //if the nativeElement of the div contain the target
      //   of the cdkOverLay contain the target
      filter((x:any)=>
    {
      const overlay=this.getCdkOverlayContainer(); //try to get the overLay
      return (!this.div || !this.div.nativeElement.contains(x.target) && 
             (!overlay || !overlay.contains(x.target))
    })).
      subscribe(_=>
        {
          ...do something...
        })
  }

A simple stackblitz

Do you use add the class "ag-custom-component-popup" to the floating element?
If not, add panelClass="ag-custom-component-popup" to the mat-date-range-picker component.
